# I am getting useless alphabets in images link

Tags: images, links, cache, plugin-w3-total-cache

I dont know why i am getting extra alphabets and question mark in my image links. Please take a look

[image]

Can any one tell me how I can fix this issue.

Comment: Are you using any caching plugin?

Comment: yes i am using w3 total cache plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to uncheck `Prevent caching of objects after settings change` in the `Browser caching` settings of the W3 Total Cache plugin. This will remove the query string from media (image, video, etc.) URLs.

But in this case, media files will remain cached by the visitor's browser until the browser cache will be emptied or query string will be attached again in URL.

P.S. Maybe you'll need to update media query string by pressing the button on the same settings page.

Comment: Already unchecked

Comment: Try to update media query string. See the answer *postscript*.